# Question about terminology regarding nets

Tags: general-topology, nets

> Show that $U$ is an open subset of a topological space $X$ if and only if for every point $z\in U$ each net converging to $z$ is co-finitely contained in $U$.

Is this question as stated correct? IMO, I think it's supposed to say *eventually in $U$* rather than *co-finitely contained in $U$*.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for the clarification. By any chance do you know if this question can be rewritten to say "closed subset" rather than "open subset"?

Comment: The most natural net characterization of closed sets is that $A$ is closed iff every net in $A$ that converges to some $x\in X$ has its limit $x$ in $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s not. Let the index set be $\Bbb Z$ in the usual order and define the net $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(n)=\min(0,n)$. Then $f$ converges to $0$ but infinitely many terms of the net (for $n<0$) are outside the open neighbourhood $(-1,1)$ of $0$.

It’s indeed more customary and correct to say that the net is *eventually* in the open set. Tails need not be cofinite as it is the case for sequences.